# Scala: Type inference and subtypes/higher-kinded-types

Tags: scala, type-inference, scalaz, higher-kinded-types

I've been playing around with Scalaz to get a little bit of the haskell feeling into scala. To
understand how things work in scala I started implementing various algebraic structures myself and came across a behavior that has been mentioned by the Scalaz folks.

Here is my example code which implements a functor:

```
trait Functor[M[_]] {
  def fmap[A, B](a: M[A], b: A => B): M[B]
}

sealed abstract class Foo[+A]
case class Bar[A]() extends Foo[A]
case class Baz[A]() extends Foo[A]

object Functor {

  implicit val optionFunctor: Functor[Option] = new Functor[Option]{
    def fmap[A, B](a: Option[A], b: A => B): Option[B] = a match {
      case Some(x) => Some(b(x))
      case None => None
    }   
  }

  implicit val fooFunctor: Functor[Foo] = new Functor[Foo] {
    def fmap[A, B](a: Foo[A], b: A => B): Foo[B] = a match {
      case Bar() => Bar()
      case Baz() => Baz()
    }   
  }
}

object Main {
  import Functor._

  def some[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)
  def none[A]: Option[A] = None

    def fmap[M[_], A, B](a: M[A])(b: A => B)(implicit f: Functor[M]): M[B] =
      f.fmap(a, b)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    println(fmap (some(1))(_ + 1)) 
    println(fmap (none)((_: Int) + 1)) 
    println(fmap (Bar(): Foo[Int])((_: Int) + 1))                                                    
  }
}
```

I wrote a functor instance for Option and a bogus sumtype Foo. The problem is that scala cannot infer the implicit parameter without an explicit type annotation or a wrapper method

```
def some[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)

println(fmap (Bar(): Foo[Int])((_: Int) + 1))
```

Scala infers types like Functor[Bar] and Functor[Some] without those workarounds.

Why is that? Could anyone please point me to the section in the language spec that defines this behavior?

Regards,
raichoo

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816251/implicit-parameter-resolution-problem-for-higher-kinded-types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking the compiler to perform two tasks: local type inference (§6.26.4) of the type arguments to `fmap`, and an implicit search for implicit parameter (§7.2) `f`. References are to the [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Things go in roughly this order:

```
fmap[M = ?, A = ?, B = ?](Some(1))(x => x)

// type the arguments of the first parameter section. This is done
// without an expected type, as `M` and `A` are undetermined.
fmap[M = ?, A = ?, B = ?](Some(1): Some[Int])(x => x)(?) 

// local type inference determines `M` and `A`
fmap[Some, Int, B = ?](Some(1): Some[Int])(x => x)(?) 

// move to the second parameter section, type the argument with the expected type
// `Function1[Int, ?]`. The argument has the type `Function1[Int, Int]`
fmap[Some, Int, ?](Some(1): Some[Int])((x: Int) => x)                                                 

// local type inference determines that B = Int
fmap[Some, Int, Int](Some(1): Some[Int])((x: Int) => x)

// search local identifiers, and failing that the implicit scope of type `Functor[Some]]`, for an implicit
// value that conforms to `Functor[Some]`
fmap[Some, Int, Int](Some(1): Some[Int])((x: Int) => x)(implicitly[Functor[Some]])
```

The implicit search for `Functor[Some]` fails; `Functor[Option]` doesn't conform.