# Scala slick sort by column string name

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to implement such method in slick:

```
def paged(page: Long, sorting: String, order: String) = {
    infos.sortBy(_.???).drop((page - 1)*INFOS_PER_PAGE).take(INFOS_PER_PAGE).result
}
```

But I don't know what to put in sortBy and how to cast String to column.
I tried simple function like this:

```
class PaymentInfoTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[PaymentInfo](tag, "payment_info") {

def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
def date = column[DateTime]("date")
def paymentType = column[String]("payment_type")
def category = column[String]("category")
def subCategory = column[String]("sub_category")
def value = column[BigDecimal]("value")
def comment = column[Option[String]]("comment")
def outsidePaypal = column[Boolean]("outside_paypal")
def outsidePayer = column[Option[String]]("outside_payer")
def sorting(col: String) = {
        if(col == "id") {
            id
        } else if (col == "date") {
            date
        } else if (col == "paymentType") {
            paymentType
        } else if (col == "category") {
            category
        } else if (col == "subCategory") {
            subCategory
        } else if (col == "value") {
            value
        } else if (col == "comment") {
            comment
        } else if (col == "outsidePaypal") {
            outsidePaypal
        } else if (col == "outsidePayer") {
            outsidePayer
        } else {
            id
        }
    }
```

but then I can't do

```
sortBy(_.sorting(sorting).asc)
```

It says

```
value asc is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[_1]
```

And I have imported

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
```

How can I sort by string column name?

Comment: Check this question, you can get the info from there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383842/dynamic-order-by-in-scala-slick-with-several-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you can do is to add a map with the string/property of the table

```
class ColorsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Color](tag, "color") with DynamicSortBySupport.ColumnSelector {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = (id, name) <> ((Color.apply _).tupled, Color.unapply)
  val select = Map(
    "id" -> (this.id),
    "name" -> (this.name)
  )
}
```

Then you only need to access that map

```
case ((sortColumn, sortOrder), queryToSort) =>
  val sortOrderRep: Rep[_] => Ordered = ColumnOrdered(_, Ordering(sortOrder))
  val sortColumnRep: A => Rep[_] = _.select(sortColumn)
  queryToSort.sortBy(sortColumnRep)(sortOrderRep)
```

You can find more info in this, like, but not same, question [Dynamic order by in scala slick with several columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383842/dynamic-order-by-in-scala-slick-with-several-columns)

If you want something more simple, then just create an Order column with your column

```
if(col == "id") {
  ColumnOrdered(id, Ordering(sortOrder))
}
```