# Cannot prove that Null <:< T

Tags: scala, option-type

In my Scala code, I have an array of `Option[T]`, like so:

```
val items = Array.fill[Option[T]](10)(None)
```

Now, I want to read a specific item from that array; if it has not been set, I want to have `null`. But when I do `items(desiredIndex).orNull`, the Scala compiler yells at me:

```
Error:(32, 34) Cannot prove that Null <:< T.
      (items(desiredIndex).orNull).asInstanceOf[T]
```

I don't fully understand this error. What I do understand is that the compiler cannot infer that `null` is indeed a valid value for `T` (since it is not known what `T` will be). Looking at the implementation, I should supply implicit evidence for the fact that `null` is a valid value for `T`:

```
@inline final def orNull[A1 >: A](implicit ev: Null <:< A1): A1 = this getOrElse ev(null)
```

Now, my question is: how can I supply such evidence? What type is `ev` supposed to be, and how can I create a value for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please explain use of Option's orNull method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467601/please-explain-use-of-options-ornull-method)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By a type bound:

```
scala> def f[T >: Null : ClassTag]: T = {
     | val items = Array.fill[Option[T]](10)(None)
     | items(0).orNull }
f: [T >: Null](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])T

scala> f[String]
res3: String = null
```

Per Pedro:

```
scala> def f[T >: Null]: T = Array.fill[Option[T]](10)(None).apply(0).orNull
f: [T >: Null]=> T
```

Comment: It T is a supertype of Null you don't need provide the classtag to make it work. Try without the ClassTag context bound and it will still work.

Comment: @pedrofurla thanks, I was too lazy/busy to try... Oh, b/c Array[Option[_]].

Comment: interestingly this promotes AnyVal to Any.

Answer (score 3):

While the solution given by som-snytt is simpler and better for this specific case, to answer the questions directly:

> What type is ev supposed to be

[`Null <:< A1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/?_ga=1.159081978.1907900041.1427697475#scala.Predef$$$less$colon$less) (this is just a different way to write `<:<[Null, A1]`).

> and how can I create a value for it

For a specific type you don't need to, the compiler will provide this evidence itself (using `scala.Predef.$conforms`). But when working with a generic `T`, you can just add the same implicit parameter to your method (or, for `<:<` specifically, a type bound), and to methods calling it, etc. until you come to a specific type.