# How does <:< work?

Tags: scala

```
scala> implicitly[Int <:< AnyVal]
res0: <:<[Int,AnyVal] = <function1>

scala> class Foo
defined class Foo

scala> class Bar extends Foo
defined class Bar

scala> implicitly[Foo <:< Bar]
<console>:8: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: <:<[Foo,Bar]
       implicitly[Foo <:< Bar]
                 ^

scala> implicitly[Bar <:< Foo]
res2: <:<[Bar,Foo] = <function1>
```

How does `<:<` constraint work? Or more precisely, where is the implicit definition that supplies the instances of `<:<`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do <:<, <%<, and =:= mean in Scala 2.8, and where are they documented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603003/operator-in-scala

Answer (score 8):

You can find it in [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef%24.html). Implicit method `conforms[A]` provides these evidences:

```
implicit def conforms[A]: A <:< A = new (A <:< A) { def apply(x: A) = x }
```

You can actually try to implement it yourself in order to make it more clear:

```
abstract class subclassOf[-From, +To] extends (From => To)
implicit def subclassOfCheck[A]: A subclassOf A = new (A subclassOf A) { def apply(x: A) = x }

implicitly[Int subclassOf AnyVal]

class Foo
class Bar extends Foo

implicitly[Bar subclassOf Foo]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Predef object.

```
scala> implicitly[Int <:< AnyVal]
res1: <:<[Int,AnyVal] = <function1>

scala> :type res1
Predef$<:<[Int,AnyVal]
```