# Selectively disable subsumption in Scala? (correctly type List.contains)

Tags: list, scala, contains, covariance, implicit-conversion

```scala
List("a").contains(5)
```

Because an `Int` can never be contained in a list of `String`, this **should generate an error at compile-time**, but it does not.

It wastefully and silently tests every `String` contained in the list for equality to `5`, which can never be true (`"5"` never equals `5` in Scala).

This has been named "[the 'contains' problem](https://groups.google.com/group/scala-debate/browse_thread/thread/d9ec90236b77cbe7?fwc=1)". And [some have implied](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4377#comment-67603) that if a type system cannot correctly type such semantics, then why go through the extra effort for enforcing types. So I consider it is an important problem to solve.

The type parametrization `B >: A` of `List.contains` inputs any type that is a supertype of the type `A` (the type of the elements contained in the list).

```scala
trait List[+A] {
   def contains[B >: A](x: B): Boolean
}
```

This type parametrization is necessary because the `+A` declares that the list is [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle/8279878#8279878) on the type `A`, thus `A` can't be used in the contravariant position, i.e. as the type of an input parameter. Covariant lists (which must be immutable) are [much more powerful for extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266596/why-avoid-subtyping/8352969#8352969) than invariant lists (which can be mutable).

`A` is a `String` in the problematic example above, but `Int` is not a supertype of `String`, so what happened? The [implicit subsumption](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4377#comment-67659) in Scala, decided that `Any` is a mutual supertype of both `String` and `Int`.

The creator of Scala, Martin Odersky, [suggested](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4377#comment-67646) that a fix would be to limit the input type `B` to only those types that have an equals method that `Any` doesn't have.

```scala
trait List[+A] {
   def contains[B >: A : Eq](x: B): Boolean
}
```

But that doesn't solve the problem, because two types (where the input type is not supertype of the type of the elements of the list) might have a mutual supertype which is a subtype of `Any`, i.e. also a subtype of `Eq`. Thus, it would compile without error and the incorrectly typed semantics would remain.

Disabling implicit subsumption every where is [not an ideal solution](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4377#comment-67657) either, because implicit subsumption is why the following example for subsumption to `Any` works. And we wouldn't want to be forced to use type casts when the receiving site (e.g. passing as a function argument) has correctly typed semantics for a mutual supertype (that might not even be `Any`).

```scala
trait List[+A] {
   def ::[B >: A](x: B): List[B]
}

val x : List[Any] = List("a", 5) // see[1]
```

[[1] List.apply calls the :: operator](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/diving-into-scala).

So my question is what is the best fix to this problem?

My tentative conclusion is that implicit subsumption should be turned off at the definition site where the semantics are otherwise not typed correctly. I will be providing an answer that shows how to turn off implicit subsumption at the method definition site. Are there alternative solutions?

Please note this problem is general, and not isolated to lists.

**UPDATE**: I have [filed an improvement request](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7857) and started a [scala discussion thread on this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/B6f-iubR9Mk). I have also added comments under Kim Stebel's and Peter Schmitz's answers showing that their answers have erroneous functionality. Thus there is no solution. Also at the aforementioned discussion thread, I explained why I think soc's answer is not correct.

Comment: Since my rep is < 100, I have to wait 8 hours before I can post my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a legitimate solution to at least some of the problem posted here - I mean, the issue with `List("1").contains(1)`:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sC42GKY7WvztXzgWPGDqFukZ0smZFmNnQksD_lJzm20/edit

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is somewhat **incorrect**, and only achieves the opposing functionality as Kim Stebel's and my answer. `(new Super) contains (new Sub)` *correctly* does not generate an error. However, `(new Sub) contains (new Super)` won't compile! Same but opposing problem that I discovered in my answer, c.f. the types `Super` and `Sub` in my answer. And your solution has high overhead, and Stebel's is not as well integrated, thus my answer remains the best so far. The only solution is as I have described the my **UPDATE** on my question. I upvoted for your cleverness.

Comment: I decided your answer is best (of the worst), because although it has high overhead and will not allow inputting supertypes, it is the only one that [allows us to sort of experiment with selective disabling of subsumption](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/LWBz3-Q0pNI/TiPDzojXmqIJ) in a somewhat reasonable way.

Comment: A solution without summary which is complete dependent of a different site isn't close to optimal.

Answer (score 12):

This sounds good in theory, but falls apart in real life in my opinion.

`equals` is not based on types and `contains` is building on top of that.

That's why code like `1 == BigInt(1)` works and returns the result most people would expect.

In my opinion it doesn't make sense to make `contains` more strict than `equals`.

If `contains` would be made more strict, code like `List[BigInt](1,2,3) contains 1` would stop working completely.

I don't think “unsafe” or “not type safe” are the right terms here, by the way.

Comment: It depends on the semantics of `List.contains`. If it is documented to test whether the list actually _contains_ the input, e.g. `BitInt`, then turning off implicit subsumption is the correct solution. If it is documented to test whether any element of the list _equals_ the input, then your point is valid. I would favor another method, `containsEqual`. Equality [is slated for improvement](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/4793), perhaps the [Comparable solution](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4377#comment-67613) is better.

Comment: I edited my question and changed "type unsafe" to "correctly typed semantics" per your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Well to be fair, that `List[BigInt](1,2,3)` doesn't contain `1`, it contains a `BigInt(1)`. Just like `List('1','2','3')` doesn't contain `1`. So when you say "falls apart in real life", you're basically saying "type safety isn't always convenient". Which is certainly true. But it is an issue of "type safety", imho.

Comment: I know that, but what is the semantic difference between `1` and `BigInt(1)`? Imho, there is none. Both represent the idea `1`. The underlying implementation shouldn't play a role here.

Comment: @soc discarding typing provides unityped semantics (e.g. this problem with `Any.equals`). `Int` can't hold a `BigInt`. `Int` could be a subtype of `BigInt`. "Looks like" is not semantics, e.g. the same user-defined operator or method name defined in 2 classes doesn't necessarily have the same semantics at the use-site (because it doesn't have the same type for `this`).

Comment: If `BigInt(1) == 1` then I think that it should also hold that `BigInt(1) + someLargeValue == 1 + someLargeValue`. Which is not generally true. `1` and `BigInt(1)` *are* different. (Though personally, I’d like to have the literal `1` resolve to an unbounded `BigInt` implementation and maybe use `1L` and `1I` as literals of type `Int64` and `Int32`.)

Comment: @debilski It is not because `BigInt(1) == 1`, that the property for addition should hold. The [equivalence relation](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html) for `==` doesn't require that property for addition. That property will be true, given `Int.+ : BigInt => BigInt` exists, which is the point I made that `+` may look the same at the use-site, but it has a different type for `this` (and thus different denotational semantics).

Comment: @soc `List[BigInt](1,2,3).contains(4)` is slower than `List[BigInt](1,2,3).contains(BigInt(4))` in current `contains` implementation because the BigInt.equals(x: BigInt) is is [faster than BigInt.equals(x: Any)](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/math/BigInt.scala#L1). Since there is an implicit conversion `Int => BigInt`, my answer "doesn't fall apart" and is faster than current implementation of `contains` because it will force the implicit conversion for `List[BigInt](1,2,3).contains(4)`.

Comment: You are basically arguing that throwing away typing (subsumption to `Any`) does not matter. Also this overzealous (or at least not selectively disable-able) [Scala subsumption is causing a more general problem](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/LWBz3-Q0pNI/rWG4hImvCQgJ).

Comment: I agree with @soc. contains does not use `eq`, it uses `==`/`equals`. Whether you are happy about that is a separate discussion.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use an equality typeclass?

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> class EQ[A](a1:A) { def ===(a2:A) = a1 == a2 } 
defined class EQ

scala> implicit def toEQ[A](a1:A) = new EQ(a1)
toEQ: [A](a1: A)EQ[A]

scala> l exists (1===)
res7: Boolean = true

scala> l exists ("1"===)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String => Boolean
 required: Int => Boolean
              l exists ("1"===)
                           ^

scala> List("1","2")
res9: List[java.lang.String] = List(1, 2)

scala> res9 exists (1===)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Boolean
 required: java.lang.String => Boolean
              res9 exists (1===)
```

Comment: It doesn't pimp list at all. Also, the example clearly shows that `===` doesn't work with String on one side and Int on the other.

Comment: This problem was already solved in Haskell 13 years ago with the Eq typeclass.

Comment: Nope, this is much better because it still supports subtyping.

Comment: Your answer is **incorrect**. `List(new Sub) exists ((new Super)===)` *correctly* does not generate an error. However, `List(new Super) exists ((new Sub)===)` won't compile! Same problem that I discovered in my answer, c.f. the types `Super` and `Sub` in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstand Martin's solution, it is not `B <: Eq`, it is `B : Eq`, which is a shortcut for

```
def Contains[B >: A](x: B)(implicit ev: Eq[B])
```

And `Eq[X]` would then contains a method

```
def areEqual(a: X, b: X): Boolean
```

This is not the same as moving the equals method of Any a little lower in the hierarchy, which would indeed solve none of the problem of having it in Any.

Comment: I did conflate `<:` and `:`. However, if the input argument type and `A` have a mutual supertype `B` due to implicit subsumption, an evidence of `Eq[B]` allows for compiling `List.contains` on an input type that can _never be contained_ in the list.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. It is based on the idea that an object can Equal (either Any.equals or with an Eq) only an object of the exact same type. This is not true in general (see equality of collections). Your question is still interesting when you happen to know this is the case.

Comment: Exact, or a subtype which inherits the same equals method. `Any.equals` doesn't enforce this subtyping requirement in general, but afaics [Eq will](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9423), thus needs my answer. Impossible to enforce this subtyping requirement on not just collections but any parameterized type, due to erasure? Wouldn't the `implicit eql : Eq[B]` select different instances for each type parameterization within the parameter `B`? Perhaps a two parameter `Eq[A,B]` would work better than Martin's proposal. Would `1 == BigInt(1)` be support by an implicit conversion, `Int => BitInt`?

Answer (score 3):

In my library extension I use:

```
class TypesafeEquals[A](val a: A) {
  def =*=(x: A): Boolean = a == x
  def =!=(x: A): Boolean = a != x
}
implicit def any2TypesafeEquals[A](a: A) = new TypesafeEquals(a)


class RichSeq[A](val seq: Seq[A]) { 
  ...
  def containsSafely(a: A): Boolean = seq exists (a =*=)
  ...
}
implicit def seq2RichSeq[A](s: Seq[A]) = new RichSeq(s)
```

So I avoid calling `contains`.

Comment: Your answer is **incorrect**. Try it on the types `Super` and `Sub` as I explain both in my answer and also in a comment under Kim Stebel's **incorrect** answer.

Answer (score 3):

The examples use `L` instead of `List` or `SeqLike`, because for this solution to be applied to preexisting `contains` method of those collections, it would require a change to the preexisting library code. One of the goals is the best way to do equality, not the best compromise to interopt with the current libraries (although backwards compatibility needs to be considered). Additionally, my other goal is this answer is generally applicable for any method function that wants to selectively disable the implicit subsumption feature of the Scala compiler for any reason, not necessarily tied to the equality semantics.

```scala
case class L[+A]( elem: A )
{
   def contains[B](x: B)(implicit ev: A <:< B) = elem == x
}
```

The above generates an error as desired, assuming the desired semantics for `List.contains` is the input should be equal to *and a supertype* of the contained element.

```
L("a").contains(5)
error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: <:<[java.lang.String,Int]
       L("a").contains(5)
                      ^
```

The error is not generated when implicit subsumption was not required.

```scala
scala> L("a").contains(5 : Any)
defined class L

scala> L("a").contains("")
defined class L
```

This disables the implicit subsumption (selectively at the method definition site), by requiring the input parameter type `B` to be the same as the argument type passed as input (i.e. not implicitly subsumable with `A`), and then separately [require implicit evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427759) that `B` is a, or has an implicitly subsumable, supertype of `A`.]

---

**UPDATE May 03, 2012**: The code above is not complete, as is shown below that turning off all subsumption at the method definition-site does not give the desired result.

```scala
class Super
defined class Super
class Sub extends Super
defined class Sub
```

```scala
L(new Sub).contains(new Super)
defined class L
```

```scala
L(new Super).contains(new Sub)
error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: <:<[Super,Sub]
       L(new Super).contains(new Sub)
                            ^
```

The only way to get the desired form of subsumption, is to also cast at the method (call) use-site.

```scala
L(new Sub).contains(new Super : Sub)
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Super
 required: Sub
       L(new Sub).contains(new Super : Sub)
                           ^
```

```scala
L(new Super).contains(new Sub : Super)
defined class L
```

---

Per [soc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360526), the current semantics for `List.contains` is that the input should be equal to, but not necessarily a supertype of the contained element. This assumes `List.contains` promises any matched item only equals and is not required to be a (subtype or) copy of an instance of the input. The current universal equality interface `Any.equals : Any => Boolean` is unityped, so equality doesn't enforce a subtyping relationship. If this is the desired semantics for `List.contains`, subtyping relationships can't be employed to optimize the compile-time semantics, e.g. disabling implicit subsumption, and we are stuck with the potential semantic inefficiencies that degrade runtime performance for `List.contains`.

While I will be studying and thinking more about equality and contains, afaics my answer remains valid for the general purpose of selectively disabling implicit subsumption at the method definition site.

My thought process is also ongoing holistically w.r.t. the best model of equality.

---

**Update**: I added a comment below [soc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360526), so I now think his point is not relevant. Equality should always be based on a subtyped relationship, which afaics is what Martin Odersky [is proposing](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9423) for the new equality overhaul (see also his [version](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4377#comment-67646) of `contains`). Any ad-hoc polymorphic equivalence (e.g. `BitInt(1) == 1`) can be handled with implicit conversions.  I explained in my comment below [didierd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8362378) that without my improvement below, afaics Martin's proposed `contains` would have a semantic error, whereby a mutual implicitly subsumed supertype (other than `Any`) will select the wrong implicit instance of `Eq` (if one exists, else unnecessary compiler error). My solution disables the implicit subsumption for this method, which is the correct semantics for the subtyped argument of `Eq.eq`.

```scala
trait Eq[A]
{
   def eq(x: A, y: A) = x == y
}

implicit object EqInt extends Eq[Int]
implicit object EqString extends Eq[String]

case class L[+A]( elem: A )
{
   def contains[B](x: B)(implicit ev: A <:< B, eq: Eq[B]) = eq.eq(x, elem)
}
L("a").contains("")
```

Note `Eq.eq` can be optionally replaced by the `implicit object` (not overridden because there is no virtual inheritance, see below).

Note that as desired, `L("a").contains(5 : Any)` no longer compiles, because `Any.equals` is no longer used.

We can abbreviate.

```scala
case class L[+A]( elem: A )
{
   def contains[B : Eq](x: B)(implicit ev: A <:< B) = eq.eq(x, elem)
}
```

---

**Add**: The `x == y` must be a virtual inheritance call, i.e. `x.==` should be declared `override`, because there is [no virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8438947/615784) in the `Eq` typeclass. The type parameter `A` is invariant (because `A` is used in the contravariant position as input parameter of `Eq.eg`). Then [we can define](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8438947/615784) an `implicit object` on an interface (a.k.a. `trait`).

Thus, the `Any.equals` override must still check if the concrete type of the input matches. That overhead can't be removed by the compiler.

Comment: The runtime efficiency pretty much depends on the implementation of `equals` ... regardless whether you compare "based on types" or "based on values".

Comment: A program rejected by the compiler cannot have any impact on runtime efficiency ...

Comment: @soc If the compiler rejects an operation which will _always_ return false and which the runtime would otherwise perform, the runtime efficiency has been improved. Martin Odersky [mentioned this](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4377#comment-67673).

Comment: @soc Also unreachable expression branches are prevented.

Comment: @soc That is not an increase in the efficiency of compilation. The programmer's efficiency is increased by preventing those cases of human error, thus faster runtimes. I will change "runtime inefficiencies" to "semantic inefficiencies that degrade runtime performance". Thank you.