# About generics in Java and Scala

Tags: scala, generics, subtyping

I am confused by the generic subtyping.

In Java, if type `A` is a subtype of `B`, generic type `C<A>` and `C<B>` are invariant. For instance, `ArrayList<Base>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<Derived>`.

However, in Scala, generic type `C<A>` and `C<B>` are covariant if type `A` is a subtype of `B`. So what's the property of generic class in Scala has but not in Java?

Comment: I don't really understand what your question means.

Comment: In Scala we write `C[A]` and `C[B]`, and no, they are not subtypes of one another *by default*. Only if you declare `C` as `class C[+T]`, and the compiler will let you do that if `T` only appears in covariant positions in `C`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth In conclude, my question is if type A is a subtype of B and generic type C[A] is also the subtype of C[B], what the property of such generic type has?

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for correcting about the syntax. You are correct for the explanation of class C[+T].

Comment: @user1391576: Your question says:`ArrayList<Base> is not a subtype of ArrayList<Derived>` but I guess what you want to ask is `ArrayList<Derived> is not a subtype of ArrayList<Base>`, don't you?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Firstly note that variance is a property of generic *type parameters*, not of the *parameterized types* themselves.

Secondly: you are wrong about scala - type parameters are invariant by default. Let us investigate!

### Java

Java has *use-site variance annotations*. That is, you can declare methods like this:

```
boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c);
```

There is, however, one form of "parameterized type" (I use the term loosely) in which the type parameters are covariant: Java Arrays! (This is actually insane because Arrays are mutable and hence it is easy to circumvent the type system). Consider the following:

```
public static void subvert(Object[] arr) { arr[0] = "Oh Noes!"; }
```

And then:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[1];
subvert(arr); //this call is allowed as arrays are covariant
Integer i = arr[0];
```

A good interview question this one: *what happens?*

### Scala

In Scala, you have **declaration-site variance**. That is, the variance of a type parameter is declared alongside the parameter (using the annotations `+` and `-`):

```
trait Function1[-I, +O]
```

This says that the trait `Function1` has two type parameters, `I` and `O` which are contra- and co-variant respectively. **If no `+/-` annotation is declared**, then **the type parameter is invariant**. For example, Set is invariant in its type parameter:

```
scala> def foo(set: Set[Any]) = ()
foo: (set: Set[Any])Unit

scala> Set(1)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1)

scala> foo(res4)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
 required: Set[Any]
Note: Int <: Any, but trait Set is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
              foo(res4)
                  ^
```

List is however, declared as being covariant:

```
scala> def bar(list: List[Any]) = ()
bar: (list: List[Any])Unit

scala> List(1)
res6: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> bar(res6)
```

### Why not ask the compiler?

Another way of demonstrating this is to ask the compiler directly for subtype-evidence:

```
scala> class Cov[+A]
defined class Cov

scala> implicitly[Cov[Int] <:< Cov[Any]]
res8: <:<[Cov[Int],Cov[Any]] = <function1>
```

But with an invariant type parameter

```
scala> class Inv[A]
defined class Inv

scala> implicitly[Inv[Int] <:< Inv[Any]]
<console>:9: error: Cannot prove that Inv[Int] <:< Inv[Any].
              implicitly[Inv[Int] <:< Inv[Any]]
                        ^
```

Lastly, contravariance:

```
scala> class Con[-A]
defined class Con

scala> implicitly[Con[Any] <:< Con[Int]]
res10: <:<[Con[Any],Con[Int]] = <function1>
```

[See also identifier `<:<`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603003/operator-in-scala)