# testing if a given instance is a (sub)class of a given Class in scala

Tags: scala, types

say your given an instance of `List[Class[_ <: Base]]`, and say that many classes extends `Base`:

```
class A extends Base
class B extends Base
class C extends A
```

etc'...
now, the given list may contain only some classes. e.g. : `val classes = classOf[A] :: Nil`, well, how can i test when i get an instantiated `val` if it's class is of type that is found in the list, or if it a subclass for a class in the list? i.e. how would you implement:
`def testClass(class : List[Class[_ <: Base]], instance : Base) : Boolean`
when:

```
val classes = classOf[A] :: Nil
testClass(classes, new A) // should return true
testClass(classes, new B) // should return false
testClass(classes, new C) // should return true
```

**use case:**
i'm trying to write a generic *retry pattern*, i.e. getting some code that is very error prone, and i want to retry executing it for some number of maximum tries, when every time it fails, it should execute some "wait" method.
e.g.

```
retryRequest({
    //Some code that throws exceptions
}, classOf[SomeException] :: classOf[SomeOtherException] :: Nil,
100, {Thread.sleep(5000)})
```

well this works OK, but it won't test for subclasses of a given exception:

```
def retryRequest(req : => Unit, validExceptions : List[Class[_ <: java.lang.Throwable]], tries : Int, waitMethod : => Unit) {
    var keepTrying = false
    var tryCount = 0
    do{
        try{
            logger.debug("retryRequest, try #" + tryCount)
            keepTrying = false
            req
        }catch{
            case ex if(tryCount >= tries && validExceptions.contains(ex.getClass)) => {
                throw new MaxTriesReachedException("tried for " + tryCount + "times, but no luck. " +
                                                   "you may want to try ommitting generic exceptions types from the given list.") 
            }
            case ex if (validExceptions.contains(ex.getClass)) => {
                logger.debug("intercepted " + ex.toString)
                tryCount += 1
                keepTrying = true
                waitMethod
            }
        }
    }while(keepTrying)
}
```

i would realy want to replace:

```
validExceptions.contains(ex.getClass)
```

with something like:

```
validExceptions.exists(exClass => ex.isInstanceOf[exClass]) //won't compile
```

is it possible? how?

Comment: Maybe this questions helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603003/operator-in-scala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
validExceptions.exists(exClass => exClass.isAssignableFrom(ex.getClass))
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29

Answer (score 9):

A simpler way would be to use `util.control.Exception`:

```
  def retryRequest(req: => Unit, 
                   validExceptions: List[Class[_ <: Throwable]], 
                   tries: Int, 
                   waitMethod: => Unit): Unit =
   (Exception.catching(validExceptions:_*) withApply { e => 
      waitMethod
      if (tries > 1) retryRequest(req, validExceptions, tries - 1, waitMethod)
   }) { req }

  retryRequest( { println("a"); throw new Exception }, 
                List(classOf[Exception]), 
                3,
                Thread.sleep(100))
```

In short: `withApply` takes a closure that handles the case when one of the exceptions passed to `catching` is thrown. In our case, we simply call ourselves recursively (given that the number of retries is small, I don't think this is a problem).